# Does the GoPro Hero 5 Black have improved video quality over the GoPro Hero 4 Black?

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording

By looking at the specifications of the newly released GoPro Hero 5 and the old GoPro Hero 4, it seems to me that they may be the same since both can record video at 4K@30FPS and take 12MP still images. Does the GoPro Hero 5 Black have improved video quality over the GoPro Hero 4 Black, or is it basically the same image sensor as the previous generation but in a new housing?

Answer (score 2):

They added a few bells and whistles, but the video quality remains the same
http://vegasaur.com/gopro-hero5-hero4-comparison